# Wordpress form to shortcode

Tags: forms

I've been struggling with this for ages. I need to generate a form with some text fields and drop down options and then transfer that data to display a shortcode. Like below

```
[adds_weather apts='KSMF' hours=2
```

I need to change the data after the equals signs and then output it to the post

How can I do this? Been racking my brains for ages!

Thanks

Comment: to execute a shortcode in PHP, you can use `$result = do_shortcode("[adds_weather apts='KSMF' hours=2]");`

Comment: Thank you, so how can I use a form to change KSMF so the user can input say "EGCC" and then it outputs when you press submit?

Comment: Where's the form? Are the form values saved? How is the form used?

Comment: Basically in this instance there would be 2 drop down boxes for the user to select. The options change 'KSMF' and hours=2 with the options. So I need the user to select and then output the shortcode appropriately with options select when you hit the submit button. I can make the fields on the form but I dont know how to insert the selected options into the shortcode

Comment: I need the shortcode to render below the form

Comment: Do you have access to the shortcode's source? I mean, can you modify it?